# Asp.net core 1.0 Send Email from Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.Net Core and I am looking to send confirmation emails when a user registers from a gmail account. I used the same gmail account in a project in VS13 and had great success. Now however I cannot manage to send. There are no errors, just no emails are appearing in my sent box.

```
 public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Rentals Rated", "*******@gmail.com"));

        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = message };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "********@gmail.com", 
                Password = "******" 
            };
      //      client.LocalDomain = "gmail.com";
            await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(credentials);
            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

^Is my current attempt

in VS13, this was my working code. Not overly relevant to the question but might spark ideas. Thanks!

```
public static void sendEmail(string email, string emailSubject, string emailBody, string firstName)
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("*****@gmail.com", "****");
        MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(email, firstName);
        const string fromPassword = "*******";

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword);

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
        message.Subject = emailSubject;
        message.Body = emailBody;
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

**Note**
When debugging, the three lines after `ConnectAsync(...);` are never hit.

By removing the async methods and using

```
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
            client.Authenticate(credentials);
            client.Send(emailMessage);
            client.Disconnect(true);
```

It works fine

Comment: Have you allowed on your gmail account the access from "less secure apps"?

Comment: Yes I enabled this for my VS13 project

Comment: What is very strange is that you don't get any error, it should work, I'm using .net Core to send mails (not through gmail) and it behaves like the old SmtpClient... Have you checked the spam folder?

Comment: I have checked the relevant folders on the sender and recipient's side. What mailbox are you using? I have a few that I can try / use

Comment: we use our own SMTP server, i think it's Postfix.

Comment: The code all looks fine, you state "less secure apps" is good... Only thing I can think of is gmail flagged the IP if it hasn't connected programmatically to your account before. This should be able to be taken care of by opening a browser on the machine and logging into gmail and go through the "security question" for them to validate the access as OK.

Comment: @MadMyche what security question might that be? I've logged in, disabled access from less secure apps and then enabled it again but still no success. Please see the note added to the question above. Is this an issue or is this normal for `async` calls?

Comment: Google Security will sometimes lock and account from programmatic access when it detects a new device or IP. If this occurs you just need to log in via the browser to reset.